# Improving a simple 1 layer Neural Network

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network

I've created my own very simple 1 layer neural network, specialised in binary classification problems. Where the input data-points are multiplied by the weights and a bias is added. The whole thing is summed (weighted-sum) and fed through an activation function (such as `relu` or `sigmoid`). That would be the prediction output. There are no other layers (i.e. hidden layers) involved.

Just for my own understanding of the mathematical side, I didn't want to use an existing library/package (e.g. Keras, PyTorch, Scikit-learn ..etc), but simply wanted to create a neural network using plain python code. The model is created inside a method (`simple_1_layer_classification_NN`) that takes the necessary parameters to make a prediction. However, I encountered some problems, and as such listed the questions below along with my code.

P.s. I really apologise for including such a large portion of code, but I didn't know how else to ask the questions without referencing the relevant code.

The questions:

1 - When I passed some training dataset to train the network, I found that the final average accuracy completely differed with different number of Epochs with absolutely no clear pattern to some sort of optimal number of Epochs. I kept the other parameters the same: `learning rate = 0.5`, `activation = sigmoid`(since it's 1 layer - being both the input and output layer. No hidden layers involved. I've read `sigmoid` is suited for output layer more than `relu`), `cost function = squared error`. Here are the results for different Epochs:

Epoch = 100,000.
Average Accuracy: 50.10541638874056

Epoch = 500,000.
Average Accuracy: 50.08965597645948

Epoch = 1,000,000.
Average Accuracy: 97.56879179064482

Epoch = 7,500,000.
Average Accuracy: 49.994692515332524

Epoch 750,000.
Average Accuracy: 77.0028368954157

Epoch = 100.
Average Accuracy: 48.96967591507596

Epoch = 500.
Average Accuracy: 48.20721972881673

Epoch = 10,000.
Average Accuracy: 71.58066454336122

Epoch = 50,000.
Average Accuracy: 62.52998222597177

Epoch = 100,000.
Average Accuracy: 49.813675726563424

Epoch = 1,000,000.
Average Accuracy: 49.993141329926374

As you can see there doesn't seem to be any clear pattern. I tried 1 million epochs and got 97.6% accuracy. Then I tried 7.5 million epochs got 50% accuracy. Half a million epochs also got 50% accuracy. 100 epochs resulted in 49% accuracy. Then the really odd one, tried 1 millions epochs again and got 50%.

So I'm sharing my code below, because I don't believe the network is doing any learning. Just seems like random guesses. I applied the concept of Back-propagation and partial derivative to optimise the weights and bias. So I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with my code.

2- One of the parameters I included in the parameter list of the `simple_1_layer_classification_NN` method, is the `input_dimension` parameter. At first I thought it would be needed to workout the number of weights required for the input layer. Then I realised, as long as the `dataset_input_matrix` (matrix of features) argument is passed to the method, I can access a random index of the matrix to access a random observation vector from the matrix (`input_observation_vector = dataset_input_matrix[ri]`). Then looping through the observation to access each feature. The number of loops (or length) of the observation vector will tell me exactly how many weights are required (because each feature will require one weight (as its coefficient). So `(len(input_observation_vector))` will tell me the number of weights required in the input layer, and therefore I don't need to ask the user to pass `input_dimension` argument to the method.
So my question is simply, is there any need/reason to include a `input_dimension` parameter, when this can be worked out simply by evaluating the length of the observation vector from the input matrix?

3 - When I try to plot the array of `costs` values, nothing shows up - `plt.plot(y_costs)`. A `cost` value (produced from every Epoch), is appended to the `costs` array only every 50 epochs. This is to avoid having so many `cost` elements added in the array if the number of epochs is really high. At line:

```py
if i % 50 == 0:
          costs.append(cost)
```

When I did some debugging, I found that the `costs` array is empty, after the method returns. I'm not sure why that is, when it should be appending a `cost` value every 50th epoch. Probably I've overlooked something really silly that I can't see it.

Many thanks in advance, and apologies again for the long piece of code.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
# import os

class NN_classification:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bias = float()
        self.weights = []
        self.chosen_activation_func = None
        self.chosen_cost_func = None
        self.train_average_accuracy = int()
        self.test_average_accuracy = int()

    # -- Activation functions --: 
    def sigmoid(x):
        return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))

    def relu(x):
        return np.maximum(0.0, x)

    # -- Derivative of activation functions --:
    def sigmoid_derivation(x): 
        return NN_classification.sigmoid(x) * (1-NN_classification.sigmoid(x))

    def relu_derivation(x):
        if x <= 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

    # -- Squared-error cost function --:
    def squared_error(pred, target):
        return np.square(pred - target)

    # -- Derivative of squared-error cost function --:
    def squared_error_derivation(pred, target):
        return 2 * (pred - target)

     # --- neural network structure diagram --- 

    #    O  output prediction
    #   / \   w1, w2, b
    #  O   O  datapoint 1, datapoint 2

    def simple_1_layer_classification_NN(self, dataset_input_matrix, output_data_labels, input_dimension, epochs, activation_func='sigmoid', learning_rate=0.2, cost_func='squared_error'):
        weights = []
        bias = int()
        cost = float()
        costs = []
        dCost_dWeights = []
        chosen_activation_func_derivation = None
        chosen_cost_func = None
        chosen_cost_func_derivation = None
        correct_pred = int()
        incorrect_pred = int()

        # store the chosen activation function to use to it later on in the activation calculation section and in the 'predict' method
        # Also the same goes for the derivation section.        
        if activation_func == 'sigmoid':
            self.chosen_activation_func = NN_classification.sigmoid
            chosen_activation_func_derivation = NN_classification.sigmoid_derivation
        elif activation_func == 'relu':
            self.chosen_activation_func = NN_classification.relu
            chosen_activation_func_derivation = NN_classification.relu_derivation
        else:
            print("Exception error - no activation function utilised, in training method", file=sys.stderr)
            return   

        # store the chosen cost function to use to it later on in the cost calculation section.
        # Also the same goes for the cost derivation section.    
        if cost_func == 'squared_error':
            chosen_cost_func = NN_classification.squared_error
            chosen_cost_func_derivation = NN_classification.squared_error_derivation
        else:
           print("Exception error - no cost function utilised, in training method", file=sys.stderr)
           return

        # Set initial network parameters (weights & bias):
        # Will initialise the weights to a uniform distribution and ensure the numbers are small close to 0.
        # We need to loop through all the weights to set them to a random value initially.
        for i in range(input_dimension):
            # create random numbers for our initial weights (connections) to begin with. 'rand' method creates small random numbers. 
            w = np.random.rand()
            weights.append(w)

        # create a random number for our initial bias to begin with.
        bias = np.random.rand()

        # We perform the training based on the number of epochs specified
        for i in range(epochs):
            # create random index
            ri = np.random.randint(len(dataset_input_matrix))
            # Pick random observation vector: pick a random observation vector of independent variables (x) from the dataset matrix
            input_observation_vector = dataset_input_matrix[ri]

            # reset weighted sum value at the beginning of every epoch to avoid incrementing the previous observations weighted-sums on top. 
            weighted_sum = 0

            # Loop through all the independent variables (x) in the observation
            for i in range(len(input_observation_vector)):
                # Weighted_sum: we take each independent variable in the entire observation, add weight to it then add it to the subtotal of weighted sum
                weighted_sum += input_observation_vector[i] * weights[i]

            # Add Bias: add bias to weighted sum
            weighted_sum += bias

            # Activation: process weighted_sum through activation function
            activation_func_output = self.chosen_activation_func(weighted_sum)    

            # Prediction: Because this is a single layer neural network, so the activation output will be the same as the prediction
            pred = activation_func_output

            # Cost: the cost function to calculate the prediction error margin
            cost = chosen_cost_func(pred, output_data_labels[ri])
            # Also calculate the derivative of the cost function with respect to prediction
            dCost_dPred = chosen_cost_func_derivation(pred, output_data_labels[ri])

            # Derivative: bringing derivative from prediction output with respect to the activation function used for the weighted sum.
            dPred_dWeightSum = chosen_activation_func_derivation(weighted_sum)

            # Bias is just a number on its own added to the weighted sum, so its derivative is just 1
            dWeightSum_dB = 1

            # The derivative of the Weighted Sum with respect to each weight is the input data point / independant variable it's multiplied by. 
            # Therefore I simply assigned the input data array to another variable I called 'dWeightedSum_dWeights'
            # to represent the array of the derivative of all the weights involved. I could've used the 'input_sample'
            # array variable itself, but for the sake of readibility, I created a separate variable to represent the derivative of each of the weights.
            dWeightedSum_dWeights = input_observation_vector

            # Derivative chaining rule: chaining all the derivative functions together (chaining rule)
            # Loop through all the weights to workout the derivative of the cost with respect to each weight:
            for dWeightedSum_dWeight in dWeightedSum_dWeights:
                dCost_dWeight = dCost_dPred * dPred_dWeightSum * dWeightedSum_dWeight
                dCost_dWeights.append(dCost_dWeight)

            dCost_dB = dCost_dPred * dPred_dWeightSum * dWeightSum_dB

            # Backpropagation: update the weights and bias according to the derivatives calculated above.
            # In other word we update the parameters of the neural network to correct parameters and therefore 
            # optimise the neural network prediction to be as accurate to the real output as possible
            # We loop through each weight and update it with its derivative with respect to the cost error function value. 
            for i in range(len(weights)):
                weights[i] = weights[i] - learning_rate * dCost_dWeights[i]

            bias = bias - learning_rate * dCost_dB

            # for each 50th loop we're going to get a summary of the
            # prediction compared to the actual ouput
            # to see if the prediction is as expected.
            # Anything in prediction above 0.5 should match value 
            # 1 of the actual ouptut. Any prediction below 0.5 should
            # match value of 0 for actual output 
            if i % 50 == 0:
                costs.append(cost)

            # Compare prediction to target
            error_margin = np.sqrt(np.square(pred - output_data_labels[ri]))
            accuracy = (1 - error_margin) * 100
            self.train_average_accuracy += accuracy

            # Evaluate whether guessed correctly or not based on classification binary problem 0 or 1 outcome. So if prediction is above 0.5 it guessed 1 and below 0.5 it guessed incorrectly. If it's dead on 0.5 it is incorrect for either guesses. Because it's no exactly a good guess for either 0 or 1. We need to set a good standard for the neural net model.
            if (error_margin < 0.5) and (error_margin >= 0):
                correct_pred += 1 
            elif (error_margin >= 0.5) and (error_margin <= 1):
                incorrect_pred += 1
            else:
                print("Exception error - 'margin error' for 'predict' method is out of range. Must be between 0 and 1, in training method", file=sys.stderr)
                return
        # store the final optimised weights to the weights instance variable so it can be used in the predict method.
        self.weights = weights

        # store the final optimised bias to the weights instance variable so it can be used in the predict method.
        self.bias = bias

        # Calculate average accuracy from the predictions of all obervations in the training dataset
        self.train_average_accuracy /= epochs

        # Print out results 
        print('Average Accuracy: {}'.format(self.train_average_accuracy))
        print('Correct predictions: {}, Incorrect Predictions: {}'.format(correct_pred, incorrect_pred))
        print('costs = {}'.format(costs))
        y_costs = np.array(costs)
        plt.plot(y_costs)
        plt.show()

from numpy import array
#define array of dataset
# each observation vector has 3 datapoints or 3 columns: length, width, and outcome label (0, 1 to represent blue flower and red flower respectively).  
data = array([[3,   1.5, 1],
        [2,   1,   0],
        [4,   1.5, 1],
        [3,   1,   0],
        [3.5, 0.5, 1],
        [2,   0.5, 0],
        [5.5, 1,   1],
        [1,   1,   0]])

# separate data: split input, output, train and test data.
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = data[:6, :-1], data[:6, -1], data[6:, :-1], data[6:, -1]

nn_model = NN_classification()

nn_model.simple_1_layer_classification_NN(X_train, y_train, 2, 1000000, learning_rate=0.5)
```

Comment: that's a pretty high learning rate.

Comment: @Chris ye, I tried 0.2 before, but I thought I wasn't getting much result because of the learning rate. I tried 0.2 again now. The really odd thing is I tried the same number of Epochs 3 times (100,000 epochs). The accuracy result for the first time I got 92%. Then 50%, then 49%. Something is clearly not right here!!

Comment: Try .01 or .001 and use relu

Comment: @Chris, apologies for the late reply. Actually you made me realise relu would be useless for my 1 layer neural network. As I tried relu, I was getting my error message that checks to make sure the output prediction is between 0 & 1 (as it's a probability classification problem). This makes sense, since relu's positive domain can go higher than 1. There's no limit. It's only the negative domain outputs 0. This is why it's always recommended to use Sigmoid or other logistic non-linear functions that squish a value between a range (for the output), since a probability has to be between 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a smaller learning rate? Your network may be skipping over local minima because it is too high.

Here's an article that goes more in-depth on learning rates: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-learning-rates-and-how-it-improves-performance-in-deep-learning-d0d4059c1c10

The reason that the cost is never getting appended is because you are using the same variable, 'i', within nested for loops.

```
# We perform the training based on the number of epochs specified
    for i in range(epochs):
        # create random index
        ri = np.random.randint(len(dataset_input_matrix))
        # Pick random observation vector: pick a random observation vector of independent variables (x) from the dataset matrix
        input_observation_vector = dataset_input_matrix[ri]

        # reset weighted sum value at the beginning of every epoch to avoid incrementing the previous observations weighted-sums on top.
        weighted_sum = 0

        # Loop through all the independent variables (x) in the observation
        for i in range(len(input_observation_vector)):
            # Weighted_sum: we take each independent variable in the entire observation, add weight to it then add it to the subtotal of weighted sum
            weighted_sum += input_observation_vector[i] * weights[i]

        # Add Bias: add bias to weighted sum
        weighted_sum += bias

        # Activation: process weighted_sum through activation function
        activation_func_output = self.chosen_activation_func(weighted_sum)

        # Prediction: Because this is a single layer neural network, so the activation output will be the same as the prediction
        pred = activation_func_output

        # Cost: the cost function to calculate the prediction error margin
        cost = chosen_cost_func(pred, output_data_labels[ri])
        # Also calculate the derivative of the cost function with respect to prediction
        dCost_dPred = chosen_cost_func_derivation(pred, output_data_labels[ri])

        # Derivative: bringing derivative from prediction output with respect to the activation function used for the weighted sum.
        dPred_dWeightSum = chosen_activation_func_derivation(weighted_sum)

        # Bias is just a number on its own added to the weighted sum, so its derivative is just 1
        dWeightSum_dB = 1

        # The derivative of the Weighted Sum with respect to each weight is the input data point / independant variable it's multiplied by.
        # Therefore I simply assigned the input data array to another variable I called 'dWeightedSum_dWeights'
        # to represent the array of the derivative of all the weights involved. I could've used the 'input_sample'
        # array variable itself, but for the sake of readibility, I created a separate variable to represent the derivative of each of the weights.
        dWeightedSum_dWeights = input_observation_vector

        # Derivative chaining rule: chaining all the derivative functions together (chaining rule)
        # Loop through all the weights to workout the derivative of the cost with respect to each weight:
        for dWeightedSum_dWeight in dWeightedSum_dWeights:
            dCost_dWeight = dCost_dPred * dPred_dWeightSum * dWeightedSum_dWeight
            dCost_dWeights.append(dCost_dWeight)

        dCost_dB = dCost_dPred * dPred_dWeightSum * dWeightSum_dB

        # Backpropagation: update the weights and bias according to the derivatives calculated above.
        # In other word we update the parameters of the neural network to correct parameters and therefore
        # optimise the neural network prediction to be as accurate to the real output as possible
        # We loop through each weight and update it with its derivative with respect to the cost error function value.
        for i in range(len(weights)):
            weights[i] = weights[i] - learning_rate * dCost_dWeights[i]

        bias = bias - learning_rate * dCost_dB

        # for each 50th loop we're going to get a summary of the
        # prediction compared to the actual ouput
        # to see if the prediction is as expected.
        # Anything in prediction above 0.5 should match value
        # 1 of the actual ouptut. Any prediction below 0.5 should
        # match value of 0 for actual output
```

This was causing 'i' to always be 1 when it got to the if statement

```
        if i % 50 == 0:
            costs.append(cost)

        # Compare prediction to target
        error_margin = np.sqrt(np.square(pred - output_data_labels[ri]))
        accuracy = (1 - error_margin) * 100
        self.train_average_accuracy += accuracy
```

*Edit*

So I tried training the model 1000 times with random learning rates between 0 and 1, and the initial learning rate doesn't seem to make any difference. 0.3% of these achieved accuracies above 0.60, and none of them were above 70%.
Then I ran the same test with an adaptive learning rate:

```
# Modify the learning rate based on the cost
# Placed just before the bias is calculated
learning_rate = 0.999 * learning_rate + 0.1 * cost
```

This is resulting in about 10-12% of the models having an accuracy above 60%, and about 2.5% of them are above 70%

Comment: I tried 0.2 learning rate. I kept the no. of Epochs fixed at 100,000. With 3 attempts I got the following accuracy result: First time = 92% accuracy. Second time = 50% accuracy. Third time = 49% accuracy. That doesn't seem to be right. The accuracies are changing/dropping (especially the second time with a dramatic drop), when I'm simply using exactly the same parameters!!! I have a feeling there's something wrong with my code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting similar accuracy results. Another thing to try might be an adaptive learning rate, so that it starts out at .5 and decreases over time.

Comment: I just noticed the cost is getting to the point where it is always either 0 or 1, which means that the network is learning to always give one of those two answers, but the 50% accuracy shows that it isn't learning why.

Comment: my apologies for the late reply. Great spot for the `i` index correction. An amateur mistake from me. Thank you v much. As for your second comment, I tried 0.5 and increased my Epochs. At 50,000 to 100,000 Epochs, the thing is, I'm always seeing the same patterns: for every 70%-90% accuracy I get 3-5  49%-50% accuracy results consecutively (that frequency can be even higher sometimes). I can run this model for the same data-set and parameters many times and still get this same pattern. To me this doesn't show any real learning.

Comment: Really if anything, running the model that many times with same data-set and parameters (especially that I have v small data-set in my example code), should cause an over-fit, and I would start getting high accuracy results every time. But even that is not happening. So I'm not sure if my code for the Back-propagation maybe is not correct.   Looking at the `cost` graph plotted, when the result is 49%-50%, the graph just doesn't show any improvement/learning. The cost value stays almost the same (where it should go down over the course of Epochs).

Comment: I think I need to examine the derivative and back propagation code and see what's going on. Note, guesses < 0.5 counts as guessing 0. Guesses > 0.5 counts as guessing 1. And guessing dead on 0.5 I made as a wrong guess in all cases, which I think is fair, since it means the network is just sitting on the fence, and it's far from any confident guess towards either 0 or 1. Just setting some standards. As for your last comment, I might've understood what you're implying. What I noticed, if you look at the cost graph for 50% accuracy, the values are close to 1 or 0 in most cases ...

Comment: .. but if you look at the `correct` & `incorrect` prediction printouts, you will see something like `correct = 50150`, `incorrect = 49850` (or something along those lines depending on the Epochs). To me this shows that the `average accuracy` is being calculated correctly. And to conclude from this result, is that although the model is perhaps getting closer to the 1s and 0s guesses, however it's simply making a highly confident incorrect guess, every other guess. But why is it doing that, instead of getting better at guessing? I'm not so sure! I need to examine the code again, see what's wrong